# PrintDocument N of N Pages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, printdocument

I am manually printing and drawing a document using this class but not sure how to be able to write on the document Page 1 of 10, Page 2 of 10 etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count. use a class attribute in order to count.
Moreover you have to calc the total count.

Remember the printPage event is call for each page !!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage.aspx

Comment: But that will give me the count afterwards. I can print "Page " +count but I cannot do "Page " + count + " of ??"

Comment: That's sure, but in lot of case you know which data you'll print, so you can calc the lenght of it

Comment: I have a list of objects which can be populated with a large amount or small amount.  I am setting HasMorePages = true when I need to but I dont know in advance how many pages there will be

Comment: by browsing your data you should be able to know how much page you'll got, i know it's lazy work :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it will be necessary two printing passagens. The first will simulate the printing process, while you count the pages. On the second run you actually will send the output to the print device and now having the previously counted pages.